# sqlalchemy UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.NoneType' is not mapped

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm saving some telegram data in a database but when I try to use `SESSION.add(cursor)` I get this error: 

`sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.NoneType' is not mapped`

This is my db **init** file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

from tg_userbot import DB_URI


def start() -> scoped_session:
   engine = create_engine(DB_URI, client_encoding="utf8")
   BASE.metadata.bind = engine
   BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
   return scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, autoflush=False))


BASE = declarative_base()
SESSION = start()
```

Here is my table class:

```
 class STATS(BASE):
   __tablename__ = "stats"

   totaldialogs = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   usercount = Column(Integer)
   channelcount = Column(Integer)
   supcount = Column(Integer)
   convertedgroups = Column(Integer)
   numchannel = Column(Integer)
   numuser = Column(Integer)
   numchat = Column(Integer)
   numsuper = Column(Integer)

def __init__(
    self, totaldialogs, usercount, channelcount, supcount,
    convertedgroups, numchannel, numuser, numchat, numsuper,
):

    self.totaldialogs = totaldialogs
    self.usercount = usercount
    self.channelcount = channelcount
    self.supcount = supcount
    self.convertedgroups = convertedgroups
    self.numchannel = numchannel
    self.numuser = numuser
    self.numchat = numchat
    self.numsuper = numsuper
```

And here is me trying to add some values:

```
db = SESSION.query(STATS).first()
if not db:
    STATS(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    SESSION.add(db)
    SESSION.commit()
```

Now, when I manually insert some values with a sql GUI tool the values are added just fine. But if the table is empty the error comes out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to long codes so I made a big mistake and I was adding the None from the db and adding it back. assigning STATS(....) to a variable then adding that variable worked